# HTTP PUT invalidation not working?

Tags: http, rest, internet-explorer-8

I do the following using XMLHTTPRequest on IE 8:

- GET /myResource (with max-age set to a date far in the future)
- PUT /myResource
- GET /myResource

The last get should as far as I understand get a fresh resource from the server even if the first request has not been expired.

But IE just gets the resource out of the cache.

Is this a known IE issue or is it correct behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known IE behavior, try disabling `cache`, if you are using JQuery make sure `cache: false`, otherwise  you can probably do something like this:

```
function random() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
}
```

And here you can append random as a variable to your request, such as:

`"here/be/url?random="+random+"";`